# Mix panel not working with Query parameter

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

I'm new to mixpanel and using it on a website (http://test.abc) for tracking.

It works fine for most of the pages, but fails for following case:

```
Fails: http://test.abc/?callback=true
Works: http://test.abc/#?callback=true
```

I also checked my function is getting called, so my assumption is that API is not getting called.

Using hash(#) in URL will solve the issue, but just wanted to know what exactly is causing the issue.

Also please point me in right direction, if looking in the wrong place.

Thanks in advance!